# Irreducibility in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

How do we know if something is reducible/irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ in terms of polynomials?

Comment: Please try accept questions when they please you. As people tend to  not answer questions from people with a low accepting rate.

Comment: What does it mean for a nonzero nonunit element of an integral domain to be irreducible?

Comment: Check this. http://maths.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/BCTCS09t4.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could be particularly brute force about it, and see whether $f\in\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is irreducible by simply checking every polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ of degree less than $\deg(f)$ to see if it is a factor of $f$.